# Rebuild Core Block as Separate Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

My goal is to create a new "custom paragraph" block based on the core/paragraph block but I would like to remove the text/background color options as well as the margin and padding options. Ideally, I would like to keep the core/paragraph separate so all the options are available for the admin.

I've tried coping the source code code from [the gutenberg block library github](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/trunk/packages/block-library/src/paragraph) and putting the paragraph directory content into the src directory of a custom plugin created with npx @wordpress/create-block.

I've updated the block.json file, included below, but cannot get the block accessible in my local WordPress.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
  "apiVersion": 3,
  "name": "custom/paragraph",
  "title": "Paragraph",
  "category": "text",
  "description": "Start with the basic building block of all narrative.",
  "keywords": ["text"],
  "textdomain": "default",
  "attributes": {
    "align": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "content": {
      "type": "string",
      "source": "html",
      "selector": "p",
      "default": "",
      "__experimentalRole": "content"
    },
    "dropCap": {
      "type": "boolean",
      "default": false
    },
    "placeholder": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "direction": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["ltr", "rtl"]
    }
  },
  "supports": {
    "anchor": true,
    "className": false,
    "color": {
      "gradients": false,
      "link": false,
      "__experimentalDefaultControls": {
        "background": false,
        "text": false
      }
    },
    "spacing": {
      "margin": false,
      "padding": false,
      "__experimentalDefaultControls": {
        "margin": false,
        "padding": false
      }
    },
    "typography": {
      "fontSize": true,
      "lineHeight": true,
      "__experimentalFontFamily": true,
      "__experimentalTextDecoration": true,
      "__experimentalFontStyle": true,
      "__experimentalFontWeight": true,
      "__experimentalLetterSpacing": true,
      "__experimentalTextTransform": true,
      "__experimentalWritingMode": true,
      "__experimentalDefaultControls": {
        "fontSize": true
      }
    },
    "__experimentalSelector": "p",
    "__unstablePasteTextInline": true
  },
  "editorStyle": "wp-block-paragraph-editor",
  "style": "wp-block-paragraph"
}
```

Comment: is this not possible already using PHP filters? You can remove those options from the paragraph block, or even create a block variant that is missing those features and WP will even create transforms for you, all without forking or copying the core block

Comment: Thank you! Block variant was the right call for me. This [WP Engine video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQEFO0GPFBc&t=9s) gives a good example of how to use and customize variations for those interested.